# Symfony 4 - Difficults with ChoiceType function

Tags: symfony

I've a Symfony 4 project.

My users can submit holidays.
There are several types of leave (illness, overtime, etc.), and for each of these types, they have a balance.

When they submit a leave, they must choose from the list of leave types the type they wish. But I want to display in this list only those whose balance is greater than 0.

So, in my form I've:

```
        ->add('typeConge', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => TypeConge::class,
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => "Type d'absence",
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
        ])
```

And in my User entity, I've the function to take only typeConges with positive balance:

```
public function getSoldesActif()
{
    $soldesTypesConge = $this->soldeConges;

    foreach ($soldesTypesConge as $solde) {
        if ($solde->getSolde() == 0) {
            $soldesTypesConge->removeElement($solde);
        }
    }

    return $soldesTypesConge;
}
```

But even with the documentation, I don't understand how can I affect this list ?
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`query_builder`-option on the entity type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) to specify which entities are displayed.

It should probably look roughly, something like this:

```php
->add('typeConge', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => TypeConge::class,
    'label' => false,
    'placeholder' => "Type d'absence",
    'choice_label' => 'nom',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $repo) {
        $builder = $repo->createQueryBuilder('typeConge');

        return $builder->where('typeConge.solde > 0');
    },
])
```

The query builder is responsible for which entities are fetched and then displayed in the list. By default it will fetch all entities and with the `query_builder`-option you can restrict this to your liking using the ORM-query builder from Doctrine.

There is also an example in the docs, you can use as reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder

Comment: In fact, I've an entity TypeConge with some names like (CA, Maladie, heure supp), an entity SoldeConges with a balance and a TypeConge, and an User which have a collection of SoldeConges. I would like, for each user, take in the user.soldeConges the elements which are superior that 0

Comment: I am not sure how the entities relate to each other, but it should not be a problem. You can also `join()` other entities with the query builder. One thing you have to look out for, is that the base entity to work with is the one being used in the entity-type (TypeConge, if I understand correctly). If it helps you can write a plain SQL query and attach it to your question and people might be able to "translate" it into builder syntax. You can also read up on how to use the QueryBuilder in the docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html